# JavaFX gradle resources (bundles)

Tags: gradle, javafx, resources

I run a multi-module JavaFX app with gradle support (`javafx-gradle-plugin 8.8.2`). When I build the app everything is working fine, even native packages are produced without an issue - but I am not able to include Resources-Bundles (e.g. for translations). 
Please let me know where to put them and how to reference in the Java-code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

K, got a solution working. Hopefully it will help others in the future:

**MainEventContainer.java:**

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("UIResources", new Locale("de"));
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/event_container.fxml"), bundle);
Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
EventContainerController controller = fxmlLoader.getController();

System.out.println(bundle.getString("greeting"));

Scene scene = initScene(primaryStage, root);

scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/styles.css");

// ...
}
```

**UIResources.properties:**

```
greeting=Hello
```

**UIResources_de.properties:**

```
greeting=Hallo
```

**styles/styles.css:**

```
.button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #81C784;
}
```

**event_container.fxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<VBox fx:id="root" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="500.0"
      xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.112" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      fx:controller="com.kjtech.EventContainerController">
   ...
</VBox>
```

**project structure:**

[image: proj-struc]

For the gradle-part just follow the docs [here](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin).

If you have any question, feel free to ask.

Comment: Just to mention: this is nothing javafx-gradle-plugin related (as far as I can see). *Disclaimer:* I'm the creator of that plugin.

Comment: I know :) Really great work you provide. Thank you so much. Back in 2014 I spent many painful hours until I understood that it isn't the easiest task to ship a JavaFX app with an app-icon. Your plugin does the job without any hassle. Kudos to you!

Comment: ... the reason why I wrote about the plugin was that the project structure seems to be different on a gradle/maven vs. "default IntelliJ Application" config. - and I guess the process of packaging the resources differs, too (but maybe I'm wrong...)